# Shortest Path Between Origin to Any Point On the Graph

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path

I haven't been able to figure this problem out in a long time. Let's say that we have a 2D plane with a predefined root which is always at the origin of (0,0). This 2D plane will not have a restriction on how large it can be.

Let's also say that a user can input however many finite number of points on this graph (and each point can lie ANYWHERE on this plane). These points are defined as S0, S1,... Sn and the user also gives the respective X,Y coordinate location of these points.

I want to find the shortest path length from the root point to every point on the graph.

What do I mean by this?: Well, let's say that the shortest path has been determined to be 6. What this means is that the path length from the root point to a point S0 is 6, the path length from root to S1 is 6, the path length from root to Sn is 6.

WHAT I HAVE DONE TO TRY TO SOLVE THIS PROBLEM:

See my diagram:
**DISCLAIMER: The purpose of my diagram is to show you my thought process. It is NOT representative of how I want to approach this problem.**
[image]

In this example that I have created, assume that all points are evenly spaced apart. What I tried to do was keep finding the midpoints between points. For example, midpoint between S0 and S1 is A. Midpoint between S2 and S3 is B. And midpoint between A and B is C. Root heads on over to C, and can travel an equal distance to any point on the graph. **The shortest path length from root to ANY point on the graph is 4, in this example. In other words, I want the shortest way to get from root to S0 that is equivalent to the shortest way to get from root to S1 that is equivalent to the shortest way to get from root to S2 that is equivalent to the shortest way to get from root to S3**

The problem is that this method will not work ALL the time, especially when you have odd number of nonroot points that are randomly scattered across the plane. I am not able to find an algorithm. Does anyone have any pointers/tips for me?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question.  The user defines points, S0, S1 etc, but I don't understand where the lines are coming from.  The shortest path between any two points is a straight line between them.  What am I missing?  A, B, and C seem completely arbitrary.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I don't quite understand your confusion. The lines represent the path that I am drawing to better represent the path length. S0, S1, S2, and S3 are points on the graph and A, B, and C are the midpoints.

Comment: Then why create them, in your example the shortest distance between S0 and S2 is a straight line between them.  Why bother with mid-points?  (shortest distance without A, B, and C, from root to S0 and S3 is 2mm assuming 90 degree angles).

Comment: @JoffreyBaratheon is that euclidean distance or manhattan distance?

Comment: @ErikPhilips I don't care about the shortest distance between S0 and S2. I care about the shortest distance from root to S0, from root to S1, from root to S2, and from root to S3 that are all equal. In this example, the shortest distance from root to ANY point is 4.

Comment: @JoffreyBaratheon it sounds like what you want is to find a point that has the least distance from all other points.  Then that point is the first node (point) from the root to all other points.  Since the user can enter points how does it work if there does not exist a point that are all Equidistant?

Comment: @ErikPhilips No, that is not at all what I want. In all honesty, I am not sure how much clearer I can be. I want to find the shortest possible path from root to any point on the graph. Meaning if the path length from root to S0 is 4, the path length of root to Sn also has to be 4. If you look at my example, the path length from root to any point on the graph is equal.

Comment: Because when you say: *I want to find the shortest possible path from root to any point on the graph.* the shortest distance from root to S0 is 2mm NOT 4mm (without these arbitrary lines you've added without any known reasoning included).

Comment: I dont get the qquestion either

Comment: @ErikPhilips Ok, how about this. I want the shortest way to get from root to S0 that is equivalent to the shortest way to get from root to S1 that is equivalent to the shortest way to get from root to S2 that is equivalent to the shortest way to get from root to S3. Does this make sense?

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but what if not all points are Equidistant from the root?

Comment: @ErikPhilips Is it possible to have such a case? In that case, if it's not possible, then I guess it can throw an error.

Comment: @JoffreyBaratheon in your example, moving S2 east 1mm causes that case if all of your lines need to be at 90 degree angles, if not then you can create arbitrary curved lines directly from the root to each point that are equidistant (the furthest point(s) from the root are then the only straight line(s)).

Comment: Did not the Greeks in Ancient times a Mister Pythagoras

Comment: @ErikPhilips They don't need to be 90 degrees. The purpose of my image was to show you my thought process. It is not representative of how the problem should be approached.

Comment: I do not understand the question.

Comment: Question not clear. Can you please explain the diagram without your midpoint solution?

Comment: @hyades The purpose of my diagram is to show you my thought process. It is not representative of how I want to approach the problem. Forget the diagram. Just look at this: I want the shortest way to get from root to S0 that is equivalent to the shortest way to get from root to S1 that is equivalent to the shortest way to get from root to S2 that is equivalent to the shortest way to get from root to S3. These points can be scattered ANYWHERE. I only made them symmetrical on the image because it was easy for me to explain.

Comment: @Joffrey Baratheon : I think, you should not emphasis on the term "shortest" here. Your main point is, you want to find A specific distance (d) which is equal from root to EVERY point. Also, you want the distance to be the minimum of all of these kinds of distance values. For example, Real distance from root to A, B, C is 1, 2, 3. But if we want to make it equal for each point, it can be 4 from root to A,B,C , it can be 7 from root to A, B, C and so on. Now, as 4 is the minimum of all, 4 should be the answer. Am I right to understanding your question?

Comment: @late_riser See Erik's answer below. I want that, but for straight lines.

Answer (score 1):

> The shortest path length from root to ANY point on the graph is 4, in this example. In other words, I want the shortest way to get from root to S0 that is equivalent to the shortest way to get from root to S1 that is equivalent to the shortest way to get from root to S2 that is equivalent to the shortest way to get from root to S3.

and

> They don't need to be 90 degrees.

So what you're really saying is:

> I want to create lines that start at each user entered point and end at the root that are all equidistant.

Find the furthest point from the root and calculate the distance (X).  To all points that are the same distance to the root as X, the line is a straight line.  To all other points create an arbitrary curved line who's distance is X.

Example (lines are not perfectly to scaled distance, just an example).

[image: equidistant lines]

Comment: Erik, This actually pretty smart. Thank you for comment. I can't believe I didn't think of this. It sounds rather obvious, now that I think about it. What if the lines had to be straight, though? How would the answer change?

Comment: Also, what I meant by "they don't need to be 90 degree angles" I meant that they still need to be straight, but they can be of any slope. Your method solves the problem, but not in the manner I laid out. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: To clarify further, the lines need to be straight. They can form any angle. Meaning, they don't need to be 90 degree angles, but they can be.

Comment: If they all had to be straight lines, then you simply build a triangle with sides (A, B, and C).  C is a straight line from the root to the point that will not be the path.  A and B summed are X, and from there you should be able to find all the angles.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to agree with Erik Philips that the connection from the origin to the furthest point should be a straight line. If multiple points share the honor of furthest, then they all get straight lines. For any remaining points, it's just a matter of where to connect into the existing straight lines.

Apply this technique to your sample problem and the distance from the origin to each point is √10 ≈ 3.16

[image]

Answer (score -1):

[Here is the formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system#Distance_between_two_points) to determine distance between two points. Just calculate the distance from root for all user-given points (s0, s1...sN) and get the minimum value from result set.

Comment: How does this answer the question?  He's not looking for a minimum value.